# MySQL - Split row into columns by colon with LOOP

Tags: mysql, string, split, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to split the following string -

```
Reference 1 Drug Name: Lisdexamphetamine, Strength: 30mg, Form: capsule, Quantity: 21 Drug Name: Lisdexamphetamine, Strength: 50mg, Form: capsule, Quantity: 21 Drug Name: Fentanyl, Strength: 100mcg, Form: patches, Quantity: 5 Drug Name: Durogesic , Strength: 25mcg, Form: patches, Quantity: 5 Drug Name: Durogesic, Strength: 75mcg, Form: patches, Quantity: 10 Drug Name: Durogesic,  Strength: 100mcg, Form: patches, Quantity: 15 Drug Name: Oxycodone, Strength: 20mg, Form: tablet, Quantity: 84
```

Into individual columns e.g. Reference | Drug Name | Strength | form | Quantity

As you can see they have a colon after each name.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT reference, email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(drugs,',',1),':',-1) AS Drug, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(drugs,',',2),':',-1) AS Strength,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(drugs,',',3),':',-1) AS Form
,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(drugs,',',5),':',-1) AS Quantity
FROM CD2015_destructions
```

but it only returns 1 row per reference number whilst there may be multiple

Current statement give me:

```
Reference | Drug Name | Strength | form    | Quantity
1         |Paracetamol|20MG      | Tablet  | 5
2         |Methadone  | 15MG     | Liquid  | 10
3         |Pethadine  | 15MG     | Liquid  | 12
```

etc..

But if my reference number has multiple drugs it doesn't display the next line like this

```
Reference | Drug Name  | Strength | form    | Quantity
1         |Paracetamol | 20MG     | Tablet  | 5
1         |Oxyconton   | 15MG     | Liquid  | 10
1         |Methadone   | 25MG     | capsule | 10
```

Comment: You should post what you have tried as well

Comment: apologies, I've updated my question

Comment: I would suggest doing this in another tool.  For instance, export the data to Excel and convert the data to columns, perhaps pivot it, and re-import the data.  SQL is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: I cant do that, it has to be in real-time for as and when the user wants to check their data.

Comment: Please provide table structure, current result of your query, and expected result. Though I have to say, I have the feeling that what you're trying to do just looks very very wrong...

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are the values that you're splitting always the same? There are so many ways to do this, but you have to provide more information.

Comment: apologies for being so vague, I'm trying to build a select query on MySQL which is not my strong point I have to say.

Comment: Hi  rlanvin, I've updated my question to help give you an idea of what i'm after..if possible at all

Comment: can anyone advise? can a union of some sort help? I'm completely baffled on how to achieve this.